# Regex to match lines between two expressions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am sorting some data and want to 'cut' out some rubbish between two bits of useful information.
Eg:

```
Useful one


rubbish
rubbish //rubbish here is covered by [.*], but the number of lines can be any number 1 or above
rubbish


useful two
```

I have successfully matched the useful parts of my information, I just need to know how to match the rubbish stuff. The pattern is as follows: useful, new line (no content), new line (no content), rubbish, new line (no content), new line (no content), useful. 
The important part of this is that the rubbish section can vary in number of lines, but always has at least one line. Im not sure if i described this very well, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know of doing this is to do this
(exp1)(.+?)(exp2)

and replace or use in code the two groups

$1 $3

where $x is the group place holder

comment me for more specific syntax

Answer (score 0):

your regexp `(rubbish\s+)(rubbish\s+)(rubbish)`

Answer (score 0):

Try a pattern like `(useful\n\n\n(.*)\n\n\nuseful\n)+`, capturing rubbish into parenthesis. Improving and applying this pattern depends on your needs and your code.